# How can I initialize a multi-dimensional array in typescript?

Tags: typescript

When using c++, I can declare a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
bool vis[11][11][11][11][2];
```

How can I declare the same array in typescript and initialize it?

Comment: Is your question regarding c++ or typescript? Please remove the c++ tag as I think you're only interested in the typescript answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example code for you using only 3 dimensions, because if using more dimensions the console.log prints the result wrong.

```
let vis: boolean[][][];

vis = [
  [[true, false]],
  [
    [false, false],
    [true, true],
  ],
];
console.log(vis);

vis = [[[false]]];
console.log(vis);
```

This is printing the following:

```
[ [ [ true, false ] ], [ [ false, false ], [ true, true ] ] ]
[ [ [ false ] ] ]
```

You can also use the following (here again, simplified to less dimensions):

```
let vis: [[boolean, boolean], [boolean, boolean], [boolean, boolean]] = [
  [false, false],
  [false, false],
  [false, false],
];
console.log(vis);
```

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you find it helpful.